# STM32L073 I2C not sending 9th clock pulse

Tags: stm32, i2c

I have an STM32L073 communicating with an IS31FL3246 LED driver over I2C. Occasionally the MCU will not send the 9th clock pulse and therefore locks the bus.
[image]

(As shown in the picture the analog signal has a valid waveform without much noise)

Before this happens there are several valid I2C transactions like this one.

[image]

Below is configuration used:

```
static void initDMA(void)
{
    DMA1_CSELR->CSELR |= DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX_CHANNEL_SELECT;
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;
    DMA1->IFCR |= DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX_CLEAR_FLAGS;
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CPAR = (uint32_t) &I2C_LED_DRIVER->TXDR;
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CCR |= DMA_CCR_TCIE;
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CCR |= (1u << DMA_CCR_DIR_Pos);
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CCR |= (1u << DMA_CCR_MINC_Pos);
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN;
}

static void initI2CTiming(void)
{
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->TIMINGR |= 0x01 << I2C_TIMINGR_PRESC_Pos;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->TIMINGR |= 0x09 << I2C_TIMINGR_SCLL_Pos;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->TIMINGR |= 0x03 << I2C_TIMINGR_SCLH_Pos;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->TIMINGR |= 0x02 << I2C_TIMINGR_SDADEL_Pos;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->TIMINGR |= 0x03 << I2C_TIMINGR_SCLDEL_Pos;
}

static void write(uint8_t *pData)
{
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_PE;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR1 |= I2C_CR1_TXDMAEN;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_AUTOEND;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR2 &= ~I2C_CR2_RD_WRN;

    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR2 &= ~I2C_CR2_SADD;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR2 |= LED_DRIVER_I2C_WRITE_ADDRESS << I2C_CR2_SADD_Pos;

    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR2 &= ~I2C_CR2_NBYTES;
    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR2 |= 2u << I2C_CR2_NBYTES_Pos;

    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CCR &= ~DMA_CCR_EN;
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CNDTR = 2u;
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CMAR = (uint32_t) pData;
    DMA_LED_DRIVER_I2C_TX->CCR |= DMA_CCR_EN;

    I2C_LED_DRIVER->CR2 |= I2C_CR2_START;
}
```

I couldn't find anything in the device errata sheet and since the MCU is the master I assume the issue is not the LED driver.

Comment: DMA flow control. Who controls it? Try peripheral flow control. In DMA stream settings. Also, every time you're about to send something clear an I2C stop detection flag. I think I had a very similar if not the same problem with bus locked low now and then. Eventually I solved it, I think it was a stop detection flag. Try it and report back. Take a look at my code that does pretty much the same thing (works): https://github.com/ellectroid/STM32F746-Disco-CMSIS-DMA-I2C-UART-Touch-Panel-Sampling/blob/main/Src/i2c.c

Comment: Thank you for your response @Ilya
- The peripheral controls the DMA, in the L073 there is no register setting for dma flow control, you just define which peripheral it's for and which direction.
- I cleared the flags before starting the transaction and it did reduce the frequency of the error but it still occurs.
- I also adjusted the timings a bit which reduced frequency but did not fix the problem.
- It seems there is no real solution that I could find so what I'm doing now is reseting the LED driver whenever the bus locks and then starting over. It works but it's not ideal...

Comment: How about you don't reset it entirely? Reset some things and see if the problem is there. Maybe you can narrow it down to resetting specific thing being related to problem appearing or not. We can probably waltz to the solution from there - we will have some idea what exactly it's related to. It's not something to be easily caught with debugging and breakpoints, so we need to get creative

Comment: Not sure how I would reset only some things. I only have the I2C interface and an enable pin which I can use to interface the device. If the I2C bus locks the only way I can interface the device is to issue a reset by toggling the enable pin. It is stated in the datasheet that when I pull the enable pin LOW the register settings are retained but the analog functionality of the device is turned off. When I pull the enable pin HIGH the I2C module is reset and the analog functionality is turn on. So it is not a complete reset I am doing but merely resetting the I2C module.